# Color full line of git status -s

Tags: git

The command `git status -s` will output a short-format git status. The status of each file will be colorized, e.g. the `M` will be red or green; however, unlike the normal `git status`, the files will not be colorized. They appear the default color for your terminal.

Is there a way to colorize the files the same as their status' while still using the short-format output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not directly possible with native git, as the [`t/t7508-status.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6ae0d972664134b82a6dd164a01e8adbebeaffe3/t/t7508-status.sh#L645-L658) test script illustrates:

```
test_expect_success 'status with color.status' '
    test_config color.status always &&
    git status | test_decode_color >output &&
    test_i18ncmp expect output
'

cat >expect <<\EOF
 <RED>M<RESET> dir1/modified
<GREEN>A<RESET>  dir2/added
<BLUE>??<RESET> dir1/untracked
<BLUE>??<RESET> dir2/modified
<BLUE>??<RESET> dir2/untracked
<BLUE>??<RESET> untracked
EOF
```

As you can see, the color is reset right *after* the short status indicator, and right *before* the filenames.

---

Note: the only evolution for now (Git 2.13.x/2.14, Q3 2017) is regarding the *branches* color.

See [commit 75177c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75177c8591aee23374c2ead9c9505ce989a8eec2) (27 Apr 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 93fdf30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93fdf301de0daa57fd6a694ad4637ec7a3a1041c) (22 Apr 2017) by [Stephen Kent (`stevejameskent`)](https://github.com/stevejameskent).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3900254](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3900254bf29e00ad72de7a5b8e354369b2b84245), 16 May 2017)</sup>

> `status`: add color config slots for branch info in "`--short --branch`"
>
> Add color config slots to be used in the status short-format when
> displaying local and remote tracking branch information.

Comment: Damn. Thanks for the clarification. I will leave this open until tomorrow in case somebody has some crazy workaround involving parsing the output or a normal `git status` output.